# PDF control in PowerApp canvas app does not render

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I have experienced an issue the last couple of days that my pdf's wont load. Initially I thought that i made a mistake somewhere, but after trying to create a new empty app with nothing else but a PDF control that does not render/show SamplePDF or other public available PDF's im convinced that there is a bug at play.

In my dev environment, an empty app with a PDF control will not render/ show pdfs, only a greyed on control.
HOWEVER in my production environment, an identical app will render/show both the SamplePDF and other PDF.

Have anyone experienced anything similar, or have an idea on how to fix this?

Greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. In the powerapp, go to **settings** -> **version** -> **select older version**